# What's the best way to fill in some uneven cracks in my garage and level it out so that I can paint over it?

Tags: concrete, garage, crack, self-leveling-concrete

I have a big crack on my garage floor.  I need to fill it and level it out so that I can paint over it using that garage floor epoxy paint.  Basically, I'm selling the house and I want to make the house look as presentable as I can.  So, what product(s) should I use to fill the crack?  Just a concrete repair kit?  Cement?

Comment: Related: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/26717/what-should-i-do-about-a-crack-in-the-concrete-slab-in-my-living-room

Answer (score 2):

The paint may cause you trouble, as most want concrete to have cured for 30 days, so make sure that the brand you use will work with your timetable.

The concrete repair products are best for cracks up to 25mm and similar depth. Larger than that would require a concrete patch 1st, filled to within 25mm of the surface. Then the repair patch (just a sanded mortar type) or a refinisher patch product, which can be troweled paper thin.

A concrete bonding agent (usually a latex based product) is used first, especially if any sealing was done previously.